# Ionic - Angular 9: fail to digest on Swiper callback

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I am using ionic to build a mobile application, the customer requests a carousel so I decide to use **Swiper** to build one. The issue is that they ask for a custom paging component which does not support in the library, so I try to build one. Here my html code:

```
  <ion-slides class="home-swiper" [options]="slideOpts">

    <!-- some code here -->

  </ion-slides>
  <div class="swiper-pagination">
    <span *ngFor="let page of pages" class="pagination-cell"
      [ngClass]="{'pagination-cell-active': page === activeIndex}"></span>
  </div>
```

And here the Typescript code:

```
  pages: Array<number> = [0, 1, 2];
  activeIndex: number = 0; // current slide
  slideOpts = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    on: {
      slideChange: this.updateActiveIndex()
    }
  };

  updateActiveIndex() {
    const self = this;
    return function () {
      self.setActiveIndex(this.activeIndex);
    };
  }

  setActiveIndex(i: number) {
    this.activeIndex = i;
  }
```

I try to catch the *slideChange* event here, so I can update the **activeIndex** in my component. The event has been fired and **activeIndex** got updated but the UI does not follow the new value.

If I set the **activeIndex** to a new number in any functions, the paging component update according to it. But if the **activeIndex** is changed by the *slideChange* event, the UI remains the same.

How can I make the UI update on the *slideChange* event?

Comment: This is probably a change detection issue with Angular lifecycle. Try importing change detection library and then marking for change. Also why are you returning a function from updateActiveIndex?

Comment: can you share a stackblitz?

Comment: The main target here is to get `activeIndex` from the swiper, so I can update it on the pagination.